# In C++, does the return value of end() function compare equal to the return value of cend()?

Tags: c++, stl

If you have some standard STL container `ctr`, does `ctr.end() == ctr.cend()`?

Is this guaranteed by the standard? Or for certain containers?

Any insight would be appreciated.